# Meteor js: use #each to iterate over and render templates in multiple html files for a blog

Tags: html, meteor, blogs

I know meteor isn't exactly meant for this but I've already implemented the website so no turning back now.

What I have is a series of blog posts. Right now they are all in one large template. I would like to split them out into a html file for each and then iterate over those html files when rendering the blog layout template.

How could this be done? I would also be open to other solutions/approaches that achieve the same end goal (allows me to better organize these self-contained static html pieces)

Comment: Why don't you just save your blog posts in HTML format inside the database and then just retreive them and show it with triple braces `{{{blogContent}}}`. Do I miss something?

Comment: For some pages, like blog posts, I really only need to add static html. To get the html into the database I would still need some way of iterating through all the static html files to do so. So how would I iterate over blogpost1.html and blogpost2.html to save them into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
{{#each post}}
    {{#if isBlogPost}}
        {{> blogPostTemplate}}
    {{else}}
        {{> someOtherTemplate}}
    {{/if
{{/each}}
```

Then you can have your templates in different files e.g

file1.html

```
<template name="blogPostTemplate">
    {{title}}
</template>
```

file2.html

```
<template name="someOtherTemplate">
    Other Template, Maybe for ads?
</template>
```

If you need a html file for each post

```
Template.blog.getPost = function(templateName) {
    return Meteor.render(Template[templateName]);
}
```

Then you can use something like this, which lets you use a custom template name passed off from a js object or collection

```
{{getPost 'blogPostTemplate'}}
```

Comment: THanks Akshat! This is getting close, but still a little off the target. If I were to take your example, what I am trying to accomplish is having a blogPostTemplate, but then within that blogPostTemplate have {{#each}} {{> blogPost}} {{/each}} and the blogPost object is a collection of all my blog posts. The catch here though is that I would like to populate that collection with other templates saved in separate HTML files. Maybe there is a wildcard operator to grab all similarly named templates, or maybe I need to Npm.require('fs') and scan the files system for the html files and parse them.

Comment: Running with the first idea. Can you do something like return Template[*] to get all the templates or return only the ones that match part of a given string. Then I could search through them for a specific naming convention, e.g. if the templates were named "BlogPostX" and "BlogPostY" I'd just do if indexOf("BlogPost") == 0 then add to the blogPosts object.